# Ooozie installation giving MojoExceptiionerror. oozie ver 4.2.0

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

Error Log

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14:13.610s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Aug 03 04:57:58 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 115M/243M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:2.0-beta-6:site (default) on project oozie-docs: The site descriptor cannot be resolved from the repository: Could not transfer artifact org.apache:apache:xml:site_en:16 from/to Codehaus repository (http://repository.codehaus.org/): Failed to transfer file: http://repository.codehaus.org//org/apache/apache/16/apache-16-site_en.xml. Return code is: 410
[ERROR] org.apache:apache:xml:16
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
[ERROR] central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] Codehaus repository (http://repository.codehaus.org/, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] apache.snapshots.repo (https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots, releases=true, snapshots=true),
[ERROR] datanucleus (http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false),
[ERROR] apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots, releases=false, snapshots=true)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :oozie-docs

ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed
```

Pom.xml file

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QGf0xu6eeNp3HGsbu_0IxCBc0LusQ5sPNisIb0EzDQU

Found no threads anywhere. Stuck here from a long time.

Answer (score 0):

could you please share the steps followed to perform the Instalation.
There is a discussion on going on the same You can check that as well.
[Oozie error while trying to execute "bin/mkdistro.sh -DskipTests"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429327/oozie-error-while-trying-to-execute-bin-mkdistro-sh-dskiptests?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

remove repository from main pom.xml
Codehaus repository